# Dying SSD found by LSPCI but not LSBLK - How to mount?

Tags: boot, mount, ssd

### Problem Statement

My SSD is clearly dying, and I want to pull off a few things before an RMA.

### Observations

When I boot, the drive is detected as present by UEFI.  Booting hangs for about 60s while the attempts to mount the drive time out.  From `dmseg`:

```
[    2.845959] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[   62.536052] nvme nvme1: I/O 25 QID 0 timeout, disable controller
[   62.644219] nvme nvme1: Device shutdown incomplete; abort shutdown
[   62.660279] nvme nvme1: Removing after probe failure status: -4
[   62.677854] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
[   62.683678] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

I can find the drive with `lspci`:

```bash
$ lspci | grep memory
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a80c
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

as well as the working NVMe drive, However, I cannot find it via `lsblk`, `fdisk`, or similar:

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                    7:0    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop1                    7:1    0 148.4M  1 loop  /snap/chromium/2295
loop2                    7:2    0    62M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1587
loop3                    7:3    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1778
loop4                    7:4    0    55M  1 loop  /snap/cups/872
loop5                    7:5    0 163.3M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1635
loop6                    7:6    0 400.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop7                    7:7    0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop8                    7:8    0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop9                    7:9    0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/17950
sda                      8:0    1     0B  0 disk  
nvme0n1                259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0   1.7G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0 929.3G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt    253:0    0 929.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgkubuntu-root   253:1    0 927.4G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgkubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   1.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

This means that I have no mount points.  I don't know that I have enough to grab onto to `fsck`.

### Other failed attempts

- If I try to boot only from the dying drive, I get sent back to BIOS, since there is not enough available of the filesystem to achieve `initramfs`.
- Using a USB adapter for NVMe does not work.  The dongle attempts to connect for ~60s before giving up.  The device is NOT found in the `lspci` list.
- Connecting the USB to a Windows box also fails, but Windows detects that a 0 byte drive is connected at that point.
- I baked the drive on the off chance that the solder was loose but nothing changed.

### The Ask

What can I do to temporarily mount this drive long enough to pull a few files from it?  My backup is a week out of date, and I would like to get that week of data back.  Can I force mount from something besides a `/dev/` path?

### EDIT - New Observations

I currently have mounted the drive with the USB mount, but the drive is 0 Bytes.  From `dmesg`:

```
[ 5748.864308] usb 3-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 5748.979686] usb 3-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=20.01
[ 5748.979692] usb 3-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5748.979694] usb 3-1.3.2: Product: RTL9210
[ 5748.979695] usb 3-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 5748.979696] usb 3-1.3.2: SerialNumber: 012345678904
[ 5748.982535] usb-storage 3-1.3.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5748.982663] usb-storage 3-1.3.2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 0bda pid 9210: 800000
[ 5748.982687] scsi host1: usb-storage 3-1.3.2:1.0
[ 5749.997797] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Realtek  RTL9210 NVME     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5749.997933] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 5750.003699] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 5750.003705] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5750.003707] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 5750.003710] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 5750.003712] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 5750.005449] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 5750.007179] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 5750.007182] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 5750.013190] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 5750.013196] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5750.013198] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 5750.016690] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Attempts at reading the S.M.A.R.T. data:

```
$ sudo smartctl /dev/sdb -a
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-58-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode
```

and

```
$ sudo smartctl /dev/sdb -d scsi -a
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-58-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Realtek
Product:              RTL9210 NVME
Revision:             1.00
Compliance:           SPC-4
LU is fully provisioned
Logical Unit id:      0x3001237923792379
Serial number:        0000000000000000
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Mon Jan 30 20:41:09 2023 CST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

suggest that only the SCSI port of the RTL9210 chipset mounted rather than the drive proper.

According to `lsblk`, the drive is mounted at `/dev/sdb`:

```
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
[...]
sdb                      8:16   0     0B  0 disk
```

Filesystems checks are not useful:

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb
dumpe2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
dumpe2fs: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I also cannot use the `mkfs` trick to guess where the next superblock should be:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
        partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
        a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
        to re-read your partition table.
```

Anyway I could flash the NVMe controller?

Comment: The drive is UEFI configured and NVMe, both of which are incompatible with SpinRite.